# Shy X short of - can be used without stating the amount by something is short?

Tags: grammar, phrase-usage

I have seen sentences like:

> They scored just shy of 100 points.

Can "short of" be used in the same way?

> They scored just short of 100 points.

I know I could say "they scored just a few points short of 100.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in this sense, you can use it that way.

Cambridge dictionary example:

> The charity raised just short of €7m last year.

Comment: Why the downvote? I quoted the Cambridge dictionary.